# BASH store command line arguments as separate variables

Tags: arrays, bash

I am writing a bash script and I would like to be able to store each command line argument as it's own variable.
So if there was a command line like so:

```
./myscript.sh word anotherWord yetAnotherWord
```

The result should be:

```
variable1 = word
variable2 = anotherWord
variable3 = yetAnotherWord
```

I have tried using a for loop and $@ like so:

```
declare -A myarray
counter=0
for arg in "$@"
do
  myarray[$counter]=arg
done
```

but when i try to echo say variable1 i get `arg[1]` instead of the expected `word`
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also, there's little reason to use an associative array if all the keys are going to be integers anyway. An indexed array doesn't have to be contiguous: `foo=([0]=a [5]=b [13]=c)` is legal.

Comment: Your current loop just has a typo: `arg` is a regular string; `$arg` is the value of the parameter named `arg`. You also appear to be writing `$myarray[1]` rather than `${myarry[1]}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They already are stored in a variable: `$@`. You can access the individual indices as `$1`, `$2`, etc. You don't need to store them in new variables if those are sufficient.

```
# Loop over arguments.
for arg in "$@"; do
    echo "$arg"
done

# Access arguments by index.
echo "First  = $1"
echo "Second = $2"
echo "Third  = $3"
```

If you do want a new array, `args=("$@")` will assign them all to a new array in one shot. No need for the explicit for loop. You can then access the individual elements with `${args[0]}` and the like.

```
args=("$@")

# Loop over arguments.
for arg in "${args[@]}"; do
    echo "$arg"
done

# Access arguments by index.
echo "First  = ${args[0]}"
echo "Second = ${args[1]}"
echo "Third  = ${args[2]}"
```

(Note that using an explicit array the indices start at 0 instead of 1.)

Answer (score -1):

I would use a while loop like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=()
counter=0
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do 
    array[$counter]="$1"
    shift
    ((counter++))

done

#output test
echo ${array[0]}
echo ${array[1]}
echo ${array[2]}
```

Output is:

```
root@system:/# ./test.sh one two tree 
one two tree
```

I use the counter for passed arguments `$#` and `shift` which makes the first argument `$1` get deleted and `$2` gets `$1`.

Hope i could help you.

Comment: There's no reason to drop into a POSIX-style loop (that uses a bash extension to increment `counter` anyway) just to populate an array that can be populated identically without any loop.

Comment: Aside from a couple of non-loop-related typos, the OP's loop works, too. This answer doesn't add anything of value.